# Intersection of two string types

Tags: typescript, types

I wanted to define a type by using generics that would declare concatenated string from two string types.
I want to allow `key` to accept only a string `"onetwo"`. Is that possible?

In my try below I get a compiler error that `'string' is not assignable to type Some` and `'string' is not assignable to type "one"`

```
type One = "one";
type Two = "two";
type Some = One & Two;

let key: Some = "one" + "two";

// my goal is this
function concat<A extends string, B extends string>(first: A, second: B): A & B { 
  return a+b; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection types represent a type that is simultaneously both member types. In your case the concatenation of two strings is actually a new string literal type.

Typescript does not currently (as of version 3.2) have any way of representing such an operation on types